# solving Recurrence relation f T(n)=T(n/2)+log log(n)

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation, recursion

```
T(n)=T(n/2)+log log(n)--------1
T(n)=T(n/4)+log log(n/2)+log log(n)-------------2
T(n)=T(n/8)+log log(n/4)+log log(n/2)+log log(n)-----------3
T(n)=T(n/2k)+log log(n/k)+....+log log(n/2)+log log(n)
T(n)=1+log log(n/k)+....+log log(n/2)+log log(n)
 n/2k=1 => n=2k
 T(n)=1+log log(2K/k)+....+log log(n/2)+log log(n)
 T(n)=1+log log(2)+....+log log(n/2)+log log(n)
 T(n)=1+log (log(2)*....*log(n/2)*log(n))
```

I ARRIVED AT THIS POINT BUT I DIDN'T KNOW HOW TO CONTENU ANY HELP PLEASE

Comment: Hint: log 2^k = k.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider $n=2^k$:
$$\begin{array}{l}T(n)=T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+\log\log n = T\left(\frac{n}{2^2}\right)+\log\log \frac{n}{2}+\log\log n = \\
=T\left(\frac{n}{2^3}\right)+\log\log \frac{n}{2^2}+\log\log \frac{n}{2}+\log\log n=\\
=\cdots=\\
=T\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right)+\log\log\frac{n}{2^{k-1}}+ \log\log\frac{n}{2^{k-2}}+\cdots+\log\log n=\quad(3)\\
=T(1)+\log\log 2 + \log\log 2^2 + \cdots + \log\log 2^k=\\
=T(1)+\log\left[ \log2\cdot \log2^2 \cdots  \log2^k \right] =\\
= T(1)+\log\left[ k!\log^k2 \right]=\\
=T(1) + \log k! +k \log\log 2 \in \Theta(k \log k)\end{array}$$
where $k=\log_2 n$.

Comment: I DIDN'T GET IT WHEY DID U PUT N=2^K THERE'ISN'T ANOTHER WAY OF SOLVING IT

Comment: $n=2^k$ is used in 3-d line and farther. I especially marked it by $(3)$ for you.

Answer (score 0):

Define $S(n) = T(2^n)$, and assume that "log" is the base-2 logarithm. Then

S(n) = $T(2^n) = T(2^{n-1}) + \log \log 2^n$ = $S(n-1) + \log n$.

That means we find S(n) by adding S(0), plus the sum of $\log k$ for 1 ≤ k ≤ n. That sum is equal to the logarithm of n!, so $S(n) = S(0) + \log n!$. A good approximation to n! is the Stirling formula $n! ≈ n^n e^{-n} (2 \pi n)^{1/2}$.

The base-2 logarithm is $\log n! ≈ n \log (n/e) + \log (2 \pi n) / 2$, and S(n) ≈ S(0) + $n \log (n/e) + \log (2 \pi n) / 2$.

Since $S(n) = T(2^n)$, we have $T(n) = S(\log n)$, so $T(n)$ is about T(1) + $\log n \cdot (\log \log n - \log e) + \log (2 \pi \log n) / 2$.